# Как исправить ошибку Assignment expression cannot be used in a comprehension iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

```
a = {i for i in range(n := int(input()))}
```

В этом коде возникает эта ошибка:

> Assignment expression cannot be used in a comprehension iterable

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {i for i in range(int(input()))}
```

Comment: А если мне потребуется это переменная потом? А создавать её отдельно будет громоздко

Comment: Вам потребуется длина множества? Вы ведь по сути ее указываете? Ее можно получить через `len()`.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно